# Does the Black Panther suit give extra speed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, black-panther

So in Civil War, the Black Panther suit seems to give the suit holder some extra speed, because the guy was running as fast as Bucky *and* Captain America.

So does it give extra speed? If so, how does that work?

Comment: In the 1960s the Black Panthers frequently had to run from the FBI, thus they developed this highly aerodynamic suit

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to [**Marvel**](http://marvel.com/characters/5/black_panther), **in the comics** it's not the suit

> T'Challa's senses and physical attributes have been enhanced to superhuman levels by the heart-shaped herb.

[**The Heart-shaped Herb**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Heart-Shaped_Herb)

> The Heart-Shaped Herb is a plant that only grows in the nation of Wakanda. In legend it was said to have been a gift from the Panther God, the local deity they worshipped, but in reality the plant had been mutated by a giant meteorite of Vibranium crashing into the earth.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities)

> As chieftain, the Panther is entitled to eat a special Heart-Shaped Herb which, in addition to his mystical connection with the Wakandan Panther God, grants him superhumanly acute senses, enhanced strength, speed, agility, stamina, durability, healing and reflexes

More information @ [**marvel.wikia.com**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/T'Challa_(Earth-616))

**Note:** There is no information (that I can find) regarding the powers and/or abilities in the MCU version [**Earth-199999**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Chaka_(Earth-199999)) of the Black Panther. Logically this will be covered in the Panther movie.

Comment: Even in the MCU, T'Challa was able to go toe-to-toe with Bucky without the panther suit, so there's *something* else going on with him.