# Has Black Panther been injected with Super Soldier Serum allowing him to run that fast?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In ***Captain America: Civil War***, in the fight scene between Captain America, Bucky Barnes and the Black Panther, there is a part where the Black Panther is running, chasing after Bucky Barnes:

You can clearly seeing he is running as fast as Bucky and is running past moving cars. This all points to him having super human strength, as a normal human can not run that fast.

### So how did the Black Panther run that fast? Did he have Super Soldier Serum?

Edit: I am not asking if the suit is responsible for the Black Panthers speed.

Comment: And if someone what to edit the title, I did not know what I should put in it.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137538/does-the-black-panther-suit-give-extra-speed?rq=1

Comment: isnt this a dupe

Comment: @Mithrandir, but I am not asking about the suit?

Comment: If you're not asking about the suit, then the answer is (as in the dupe target) "we don't know yet"; or worse, this is related to a future work.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, cool , then it has an answer based on it own merits.

Comment: @KyloRen Both of these questions could be reworded to be "What gives Black Panther his super speed?", so they're duplicates. Doesn't matter that you're asking if it was caused by Super Soldier Serum and the other question is asking whether it's a function of the suit.

Comment: @I Love You, huh , you should know better.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know what makes T'Challa superhuman in the MCU yet - that will likely be explained in the Black Panther Solo movie. In the comics, however, there exists something called the 'heart-shaped herb' that grows only in Wakanda. When consumed, it grants the user supernatural abilities from the Wakandan Panther God.